# User not in sudoers, but still can use sudo

Tags: debian, sudo

I have a user user1 that is not in the sudoers file (nor belonging to groups in sudoer) but can still use sudo. How is it possible ?

```
user1~$ groups
        user1 www-data
```

My sudoer conf

```
        root ALL=(ALL) ALL
        %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

        #includedir /etc/sudoers.d

user1~$ sudo -l
        User user1 may run the following commands on this host:
        (ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you can see, your sudoers file contains a line above which includes a number of other files from `/etc/sudoers.d`.  You may be thinking that the hash symbol in front is a comment, but from `man sudoers`:

> It is possible to include other sudoers files from within the sudoers file
>      currently being parsed using the
>      #include and #includedir directives.

You will need to show us the contents of all files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` before we can comment on why user1 has sudo privileges.

Comment: Thanks, I was sure it was commented out ! There is effectively files in sudoers.d that define additionial rights.

Comment: Whoever thought of using # like that in a config file where a # in all bar one other context means a comment needs a good talking to.

Comment: <grin> I agree, but things are even worse: it has **another** non-comment use: "*The pound sign (‘#’) is used to indicate a comment (unless it is part of a #include directive or unless it occurs in the context of a user name and is followed by one or more digits, in which case it is treated as a uid)*".  Bring forth the cluebat!

Comment: Yes, that was the one other context I was referring too.

Comment: Sorry, Iain, my bad.  I didn't know about the other one myself, until I went back a few minutes ago to look.  I suppose this is why most sample `sudoers` files ship with double-hashes as comments throughout.

Comment: `#include` is a C-ism.   It's not a comment there :)

Comment: @BillWeiss: I know #include from C but not in a config file where # is a comment ... it's just wrong

Answer (score -1):

There is a group named "sudo"; execute *sudo /cat/group* in terminal and watch output, *user1* should be included in the group at installation time.

Comment: The command `groups` in the OP shows that the user is only in one group, `www-data`.

Comment: It is a fresh install without root user

Comment: In my system groups user-i returns this output: user-i : user-i  cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner